# How am I supposed to check Defender's capability when it trusts me blindly after I mark a test malware file as "allowed"?

Tags: malware, windows-10, defense, automated-testing

With enormous amounts of fighting with Windows/Microsoft Defender, I finally managed to download the "test virus" file from https://www.ikarussecurity.com/en/private-customers/download-test-viruses/ onto my desktop.

However, Defender (on the command line) still just says:

```
Scanning C:\Users\John Doe\Desktop\eicar_com.zip found no threats.
```

No threats? You just had me work for 30 minutes straight to make you not remove the file before it ever even landed on my desktop, and now you consider it to not contain any threats? Is this just because I have "allowed" it?

My entire point of downloading this file was to check if Windows/Microsoft Defender returns a "1" code instead of "0" when it detects a virus (and what it says as text output), but now I can't even test that because it thinks that the file is not "harmful" just because I allowed it to exist temporarily on my system for the purpose of testing this?

Bottom line: I can't see any way to test Defender's output/return code for an actual malware-detected file because it doesn't even allow me to have the file on my desktop without "allowing" it, which apparently makes it believe me blindly as an authority.

Comment: Not a Window's person, so take this with a grain of salt.  While I understand your frustration, it sounds like Defender is acting in a reasonable fashion.  It is detecting a threat before it even arrives on your computer and is doing so effectively enough that you can't figure out how to get a virus on your computer without it intervening.  Therefore the only way you can download a virus is by saying, "No really, it's fine, please let me download this" after which it is fairly reasonable for it to not bug you about it.

Comment: As a very off-the-wall suggestion from someone who knows nothing about this, try spinning up a linux VM, download, zip it twice, copy it back to the host, and then double unzip it there

Comment: You could create a very simple shell script to create the EICAR file for you ...

Comment: If you add a file to any AV's allow list, it's not going to quarantine it. I'm not sure how Defender is different in this regard.

Comment: There are trivial workarounds to the problem of granting permission (create the file yourself in an editor, use scp or ftp to download it) but this question reads like a rant.

Comment: Untested suggestion: do you have another machine that could mount a share from your desktop (containing the test file), and run your "Defender test" on that other machine (where you've not said to allow the file)?

Comment: Try downloading the file with Real-Time Protection off instead of allowing the file outright. That way Defender won't block the download but will still flag the file when you scan it.

Answer (score 0):

@nobody's answer is what you needed. Here is the answer you were looking for:

```
PS D:\My_Files\Downloads> & 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe' Scan -ScanType 3 -DisableRemediation -File D:\My_Files\Downloads\Expected.png
Scan starting...
Scan finished.
Scanning D:\My_Files\Downloads\Expected.png found no threats.
PS D:\My_Files\Downloads> $lastExitCode
0
PS D:\My_Files\Downloads> & 'C:\Program Files\Windows Defender\MpCmdRun.exe' Scan -ScanType 3 -DisableRemediation -File D:\My_Files\Downloads\eicar.com.txt
Scan starting...
Scan finished.
Scanning D:\My_Files\Downloads\eicar.com.txt found 1 threats.

<===========================LIST OF DETECTED THREATS==========================>
----------------------------- Threat information ------------------------------
Threat                  : Virus:DOS/EICAR_Test_File
Resources               : 1 total
    file                : D:\My_Files\Downloads\eicar.com.txt
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PS D:\My_Files\Downloads> $lastExitCode
2
```

The exit code is actually 2 when malware is found OR when an error occurs, so I suggest you check the text output too in whatever code you are writing.